# Show activity indicator while navigating through screens in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, activity-indicator

I have a file called ScreenOne.js. My goal is to show an activity indicator for three seconds while I navigate from ScreenOne to ScreenTwo. So the flow would be:
ScreenOne -> Activity indicator (display for three seconds) -> ScreenTwo.
This is what I would like to show up:

```
<ActivityIndicator color={blue} size="large" />
```

I already have tried several ways and the ScreenOne file contains the startLoading function for the indicator. I would really appreciate your help for this one.
This is the ScreenOne file:

```
const ScreenOne = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const navigateTo = () => {
    navigation.navigate('ScreenTwo')
  }

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const startLoading = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoading(false);
    }, 3000);
  };

  return (
    <ScreenContainer>
      <Header style={styles.header} >
        <Text style={styles.textHeader} >ScreenOne</Text>
      </Header>
      <Text style={styles.message} >This is the ScreenOne</Text>
      <Button rounded buttonText='Go to ScreenTwo' textColor={colors.white} onPress={navigateTo} />
    </ScreenContainer>
  )
}

export default ScreenOne
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this

[Working Example Here](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/three-seconds-loader)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View, ActivityIndicator, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

function ScreenOne({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>This is ScreenOne</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to ScreenTwo"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ScreenTwo')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function ScreenTwo({ navigation }) {
  const [Loading, SetLoading] = React.useState(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      SetLoading(true);
      setTimeout(() => {
        SetLoading(false);
      }, 3000);
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);

  if (Loading) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <ActivityIndicator color={'blue'} size="large" />
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>This is ScreenTwo</Text>
      <Button title="Go back" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function MyStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="ScreenOne" component={ScreenOne} />
      <Stack.Screen name="ScreenTwo" component={ScreenTwo} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyStack />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```